# Does a bibliography-only citation count like a regular citation for the author?

Tags: publications, citations, bibliometrics, ieee

There is a very nice open source toolbox for Matlab which I have used for proof of concept. However, the real implementations in my field are almost always done in C++. I really like to give credit to those behind aforementioned toolbox and I have two of ways of doing so.

One is to add a sentence in the paper similar to:

> one can achieve this using toolbox Foo (Foosmith 2015)

I’m not really fond of this approach because not only does it occupy valuable space, but also somehow states the very obvious (somehow an insult to the intelligence of the readers).

My second approach is not to cite them in the paper but add them in the bibliography (can be done with `\nocite{}` in LaTeX). My question is, if I follow this path, would it count as a citation for the creator of this toolbox? If it matters, my paper is to be submitted to an IEEE conference.

Comment: You better do based on the instructions, asserted within the aforementioned package's homepage... The authors often appreciate either of the approaches...

Comment: @Matinking: What instructions? Also, I am pretty certain this is about citations as an academic currency, not about pleasing the package authors by mere appreciation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I'm not really sure if I can agree with the work `currency`, nor can I agree with @Matinking. Their work has been helpful for my research and I just want to acknowledge their work (acknowledge not in the sense of that section of paper).

Comment: @Pouya: I am confused: If this is just about being nice, why are you focussing on whether the citation “counts”? You obviously do acknowledge; what possible difference do you think your alternatives would make?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Lead Development teams of the open source projects often declare some ways to cite their work within the papers and researches, such as referencing a specific paper, citing something in acknowledgement section, etc. For example, see this link: http://pybrain.org/ The authors are welcome to cite a paper as using PyBrain library

Comment: @Wrzlprmft, I want to them to be acknowledge in a way that is good for them, i.e., increase their citations. The word currency gave me this sensation that I also would benefit from this which is not the case. I don't care if they know that I have cited them or not. I just want to increase their citations. Hope this clarifies the situation.

Comment: @Pouya: Okay, that’s exactly what I meant by *currency.*

Comment: I doubt that it's an insult to the intelligence of the readers. If they weren't previously aware of the package Foo then it's a very useful thing to say in the paper. There's no harm saying it, and many journals and conferences (including IEEE I believe) require you to have in-text citations for every item in the bibliography, so I'd say just leave that comment in.

Comment: _somehow an insult to the intelligence of the readers_ — Nonsense.  At least some of your readers are beginning students, who will _really_ appreciate the explicit pointer to resources that everyone around them assumes they already know about.  Others are decades into the future, when current common knowledge about standard software packages will have faded from memory.

Comment: If the paper is being professionally copy-edited, the copy-editor should notice any references in the bibliography that are not cited in the text, and will ask that they either be deleted or cited.

Answer (score 12):

In the main text, you could also mention the authors by explicitly stating what their tool helped you with, for example:

> Our approach was projected/tested/verified using toolbox Foo (Foosmith 2015) and later ported to C++ for performance measurements.

Apart from thanking the authors, this could also be interesting for the reader.

As the other answers mentioned, a bibliography-only citation counts the same as a regular citation, but such a citation is quite unusual and generally not recommended.

Answer (score 4):

You could cite them in the acknowledgements.

> Thanks to Foo et al. (2042) for their toolbox which helped the authors to study migratory patterns in unicorns.

I don't think it would be an insult to the intelligence of anybody.  Although papers are not a chronological description of everything you tried, if something helped you but did not make it into the final paper, it can go in the acknowledgements.

Adding an item to the bibliography without a corresponding citation is something I have not seen before (nor have I checked) and it would not surprise me if many journals would have policies against it.  At least one family of journals I know has backreferences, i.e. links from bibliography entries to the places in the main text where the citation occurs, so in this case it would be immediately obvious.

Comment: If the OP is concerned about the short sentence shown in the question occupying (too much) valuable space, I am not convinced your longer sentence helps in this respect, let alone that there *is* an acknowledgments section to start with.

Comment: Concerning the last paragraph, I think this (IMHO nonsensical) restriction to add items to the bibliography only if there is a corresponding citation in the text was discussed elsewhere on this site; I'll try to find the respective question again. In any case, how can you be sure you "have not seen [`\nocite`d bibliography items] before", unless you have, for all papers you have ever read, checked one by one whether each bibliography item is mentioned somewhere in the text?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: you may be thinking of [this question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/56970/4140), which is indeed pertinent.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I have not checked it, which is a major reason why I haven't seen it (edited for clarification).

Comment: @gerrit: Fair enough ;)

Answer (score 2):

Generally, all items in the Bibliography  (references) section are considered cited. But the fact that you mentioned IEEE means that all items in the bibliography ought to be cited in the main matter and presented in the order of citation.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have no option but to cite all bibliographic items in the text. This is the standard in most journals/styles, and it is for a reason: How does the reader know to which part is the cited article relevant? Actually, `\nocite{}` should **never** be needed in an article. But if you push your `\nocite{}` through, the bibliographic item will get indexed by the databases and the authors will get the citation.

What shall you do? Well, whatever you wish, as long as the citation appears at the right place. It's common to see the parenthesized/bracketed citation just after the authors' names in text, it's common to see them put at the end of sentences etc., some people write also things like: *The authors of (Foosmith 2015) showed that...*